# werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'about'. Did you mean 'home' instead?

Tags: flask, werkzeug

I'm trying to run this simple `FLASK` commands via `PYCHARM`:

```
    from flask import Flask, render_template
    
    app=Flask(__name__)
    
    @app.route('/')
    def home():
        return render_template('home.html')
    
    
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And got this error, google or any other posts didn't help:

> raise BuildError(endpoint, values, method, self)
> werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'about'. Did you mean 'home' instead?

Answer (score 1):

working on the exact same thing I think. Building a site using flask.

I had the same error and it was exactly for the reason answered above.

In the HTML you have to call the correct function.

Below you can see the HTML code and I had to make sure used the "home2" function (which is what I called the 'about page' function)

```
@app.route('/about/')
def **home2**():
   return render_template("about.html")
```

**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class = 'container'>
                <h1 class = "logo"> Will's website</h1>
                <strong><nav>
                    <ul class = "menu">
                        <li><a href="{{url_for('home')}}">home</a><li>
                        <li><a href="{{url_for('home2')}}">about</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav></strong>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class = 'container'>
            {%block content%}
            {%endblock%}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**

Comment: This was what happened to me, I had a mistake in my HTML template.

Answer (score 0):

#### Its possible that you are trying to access the about route in your html. It raises an error because that route doesn't exist. So you have to define it in your app.

Here's an example:

```py
@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return render_template('about.html')
```